# How to set Windows 10 notification for specific program to not disappear

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I'm looking for a way to set Windows 10 notifications for a specific program to *not* disappear from above the task bar unless I specifically dismiss them.

The default behaviour is: Notification appears in the notification area, and if not dismissed the notification disappears and is displayed in the "Action Centre". What I'm looking to make happen is for the notification to remain instead of going to the action centre. Is there any way to make this happen?

(For background, I've installed the whatsapp desktop application and coupled it with RBTray to allow me to minimise to the system tray. However, as the Whatsapp application isn't really designed to run in the tray there's no skype-like "notification icon" when a new message has been recieved, and I rarely pay attention to the action centre icon as it generally gets filled up with non-relevant items).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 you can go to Settings -> Ease of Access -> Other options.

On that screen change the show notifications option. You can select up to 5 minutes. [Ease of Access "Other Options"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Evf.png)

If you have the "Action Center" (looks like a little comment box in the lower right) also keeps some notifications.
[Screenshot of Action Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty046.jpg)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP wants it **not** to disappear at all (without action from them).

Comment: I'm going to guess by the lack of other answers that there may not be an easier way to suspend them permanently. However my method would keep it there for 5 minutes without action from them (after altering a setting once).